# Select from two different tables while using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am using Oracle SQL Dev
The problem is with using the GROUP BY

I have two tables one called CAR that holds details about cars and another called OWNERS - people have been an owner of a CAR.

```
CAR

plateNo    make

246810     Ford
121416     BMW
182022     VW
162398     Tesla
```

.

```
OWNER

name      plateNo 

Joe       246810
Greg      246810
Brad      246810
Sam       121416
Kim       121416
Sal       182022
Betty     162398
```

Im trying to list how many owners each car make has had and display make and number of owners

I can get the count for plateNo from OWNER

```
SELECT count(plateNo) AS NO_OWNERS
FROM OWNER
GROUP BY plateNo
ORDER BY COUNT(plateNo);
```

The result would be

```
NO_OWNERS
3
2
1
1
```

When i try to add 'make' to the query like this

```
SELECT count(OWNER.plateNo), CAR.MAKE 
FROM OWNER, CAR
WHERE OWNER.plateNo = CAR.plateNo
GROUP BY OWNER.plateNo
ORDER BY COUNT(OWNER.plateNo);
```

I get the error  "not a GROUP BY expression"
the result I am looking for would be like this

```
NO_OWNERS   make
3           Ford
2           BMW
1           VW
1           Tesla
```

How do I go about this type of query?

Further still how can i also display the plateNo in the result?

Answer (score 1):

Then use the correct field in the `GROUP BY`.  Along the way, fix your `JOIN` syntax as well:

```
SELECT count(*), c.MAKE 
FROM OWNER o JOIN
     CAR c
     ON o.plateNo = c.plateNo
GROUP BY c.MAKE
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause; *always*  use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this works well, i should have asked in my original post what if i also wanted to display plateNo in the result?

Comment: @zpnq . . . I would suggest that you ask another question with sample data and desired results.  It isn't obvious what you want to do, because many plate numbers probably match each make.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.make, c.plateno, count(*)
FROM OWNER o
      INNER JOIN CAR c ON o.plateNo = c.plateNo
GROUP BY c.make, c.plateno
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Another simple rule: repeat all non-aggregating columns of the select clause in the group by clause